# Laravel 5.7 unable to load `storage/framework/cache/data` and write into `./storage/logs/laravel-2019-06-11.log`

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, laravel-5.7, user-permissions

I have a project under laravel 5.7 installation and for some reason I get the following error:

```
file_put_contents(/home/vagrant/code/storage/framework/cache/data/1c/6e/1c6ea8378a1030f85a05f4cb2262de1e2164efa6): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

In order to mitigate the error I tried the following:

- Permission Based tries:

```
 chmod 777 -R storage
 chmod 0777 -R storage
```

- artistan based attempts:

```
 php artisan cache:clear
 php artisan config:clear
 php artisan config:cache
 php artisan view:clear
```

- php-fpm default user settings:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data bootstrap/cache
```

Also for the development I use vagrant with the following `Vagrantfile` located at the root of my project:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
    config.vm.box_version = "20180917.0.0"     
    config.vm.box_download_insecure = true

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.name = "myapp-api"

        vb.memory = 2024
        vb.cpus = 1

        vb.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--uartmode1", "disconnected" ]
    end

    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.111"
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8888
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2223

    config.vm.synced_folder "./.", "/home/vagrant/code"

    # Provision Scripts
end
```

But any of these failed to resolve the solution.

## Edit 1

The folder `framework/cache/data` already exists as `ls -l` shows:

```
$ ls -l /home/vagrant/code/storage/framework/cache/ | grep data
drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 4096 Jun 11 10:46 data
```

By doing:

```
rm -rf storage/framework/cache
mkdir -p storage/framework/cache
```

Resulted to the following **NEW** error:

```
The stream or file "/home/vagrant/code/storage/logs/laravel-2019-06-11.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

So in my investigation shows:

```
$ ls -l /home/vagrant/code/storage/logs
total 112
drwxrw-rw- 1 vagrant vagrant  4096 Jun 10 17:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  4096 Jun 10 15:47 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant    14 Jun 10 15:47 .gitignore
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 96507 Jun 10 18:09 laravel-2019-06-10.log
```

Meaning it has more than enouch permissions to get written. I also run the following command:

```
$ ls -l /home/vagrant/code/storage/ | grep logs
drwxrw-rw- 1 vagrant vagrant 4096 Jun 10 17:31 logs
```

Meaning that still there are good enouch permissions in order for the laravel to write into the file. Still the error shows the opposite.

Furthermore I tried this one:

```
mv bootstrap/cache/config.php ~/
```

I also tried the following:

```
rm -rf storage/logs/*
./artisan cache:clear
```

And the problem still remains.

Comment: try  delete the bootstrap/cache/config.php file.

Comment: Try removing all files/directories in the `storage/framework/cache` directory.

Comment: I tried that and lead to new errors.

Comment: Run `whoami` to see who you're running those commands as. You might need to either change the user you're on (e.g. `sudo -iu vagrant` to become the vagrant user) or change the owner of the files to the one that should have ownership (e.g. `chown <correct user>:<correct group> * -R`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the code is running as `www-data` user. To fix tat you should make a custom `php-fpm` pool using the user and group named `vagrant`.

It is achieved via this configuration `php-fpm` configuration:

```
[www-vagrant]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9001;
user=vagrant
group=vagrant
```

And use `tcp://127.0.0.1:9001` into nginx configuration. Alternatively you can use the default (`www`) pool in case that all php scripts are being executed using a single user:

```
[www]

# Existing pieces of configuration

user=vagrant
group=vagrant
```

More info is located here: https://serversforhackers.com/c/php-fpm-multiple-resource-pools (keep in mind that for later php versions replace the `/etc/php5` part of paths with the `/etc/php^Version^` where `^Version^` is the desired version of php.

Comment: and how to achieve it step by step @Dimitrios? Thanks

Comment: My mistake was that I executed php artisan cache:clear in my machine, but I should have do it in my VM(In my case, Homestead)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Docker, first enter the terminal in the project directory, then run the following command
**docker-compose exec php / bin / sh**
Then run the following command
**chown -R www-data: www-data ./**
Then, if there is no result, delete the config file once from the bootstrap / cache section, then run the following command:
**php artisan config: cache**
I hope the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that this path exists:

```
/home/vagrant/code/storage/framework/cache/data
```

Based on what you shown `/home/vagrant/code/storage/framework/cache/data` there's no project name, `/home/vagrant/code/<name-of-your-project>/storage/framework/cache/data` check your `config/cache.php` if it corresponds to:

```
'file' => [
    'driver' => 'file',
    'path' => storage_path('framework/cache/data'),
],
```

You may try to dump the `storage_path()` to see what does the path look like

Comment: The project is named `code` on a custom Vagrant-running vm using ubuntu 16.04LTS.